# Gulp and dependencies rebuilding

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I would like to either :

- have gulp to return the file dependencies of a specific target (as I use [shake](http://shakebuild.com), which will then perform only the necessary rebuild)

or

- have gulp not rebuild every single time it's invoked when there is no need to recompute what has not changed

Is there a way to do either of those ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try out [gulp cached](https://github.com/contra/gulp-cached) and [gulp-progeny](https://github.com/HerringtonDarkholme/gulp-progeny), which will handle dependency tracking for you. It has builtin less/sass/stylus/jade support, and you can also extend it by simple regex.

Comment: I know you are asking for gulp solution, but webpack also worths having a look.